# Internal server error 500 on $.ajax "POST"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been getting an internal server error 500 for 8 days now and cannot find a way to solve it.

I want to make a search option for my users (when i get them, lol). I tried `$.POST` method alone, yesterday I changed it to `$.ajax` post method, and got the same results.

I think the error is coming from the URL properties. I tested every line of code and it does work, but when I go to URL everything goes to hell... Every time I put something different than `"/wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php"` as my file path I get `404 NOT FOUND` and when I put it back I get `500 internal server error`... I had read every post that I could find on the internet and have tried many solutions and it won't work... :X

Here is my JQuery and PHP.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#food_search").keyup(function(event){
        var search_term =$(this).val();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php",
    data:{fsearch:search_term},
    success:function(res){
        $("#food_search_result").html(res);
    }
});
    });
});



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="food-search" id="food_search"></p>

<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                                PHP
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "myName";
$password = "myPassword";
$databaseName = "dbName";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

if(isset($_POST['Title']) && $_POST['Title']!=""){
$fsearch = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE :Title");
$fsearch->execute(array(
'Title'=>'%'.$_POST['Title'].'%'
));
if($fsearch->rowCount()==0){
echo 'Не бяха намерени резултати!';
}
else{
while($data=$fseach->fetch()){
?>
<div class="search-result">
    <img src="<?php echo $data['fimage']; ?>" class="fimage"/>
    <span class="result-title"><?php echo $data['title'];?></span><br>
    <span class="calories-total"><?php echo $data['calories total'];?></span><br>

</div>
<?php
}
}
}else
{
echo 'Напишете име на продукт!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your error logs for PHP's real error. You sent something to the  PHP it didn't like.

Comment: Are you using Wordpress? I see this post is tagged as such, but then why are you declaring your database credentials in your php file? That should be handled by the WP core, you're also writing manual SQL queries, which is find, but if you're using Wordpress why not use their built in methods for database interactions?

Comment: Ryan Yap i an using wordpress,but don't really want to learn their scripts and built in things(well i am using their code from time to time,but the one that i know on pure php,for example i am using their get_header(); because i know how to include header in pure PHP)all by myself,got some friends which will help for securing the website.But for all other things i am alone.Sorry if it sounds stupid.
And jay I got the logs and debug activated logs are not showing anything that  i can use,they are just showing path of fail which is givving the errror.And nothing showing in error_log either.

Comment: As mentioned above, review your error log. Also, Ajax functions differently in WordPress. There are TONS of questions on stack regarding ajax and wp, read up on it